JavaFX 21 NoClassDefFoundError in Maven Multi-Module Project
I have a Non-Modular JavaFX 21 application using OpenJFX, organized into two Maven modules:

UI

Core


When running the application directly through IntelliJ's Application run configuration, everything works fine. However, when using the javafx-maven-plugin to build and run the application, I encounter a NoClassDefFoundError for javax.transaction.TransactionManager. This class is a nested dependency, provided by another dependency.
To temporarily resolve this, I added an explicit dependency on javax.transaction, which fixed the initial error. However, I now get a new NoClassDefFoundError for a class from a proprietary library (used by our company) that the Core module depends on. This class is not a nested dependency and is explicitly declared in the pom.xml of the Core module.
Note that i don't have any problems with loading any JavaFX classes
Project Structure:

app (root)

pom.xml (parent POM)

UI (module with its own pom.xml)

Core (module with its own pom.xml)




The javafx-maven-plugin is configured in the pom.xml of the UI module, and the UI module has a dependency on the Core module.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>foo.bar.view.fx.Main</mainClass>
        <commandLineArgs>${programArgs}</commandLineArgs>
        <options>
            <option>jvm arg 1</option>
            <option>jvm arg 2</option>
        </options>
        <!--       THIS DIDN't WORK <runtimePathOption>CLASSPATH</runtimePathOption>-->
    </configuration>

What could be the issue here?
With the javafx-maven-plugin i would expect it to work the same if not better as with the intellij run configuration. I can't find any similar issues online. I only people having issues with JavaFX classes not being found.

I probably don't understand the true issue, but I will give it a try. Why can't you publish the Core and UI jars to your local Maven repository and use them as dependencies in the overarching project?

A minimal example illustrating @SedJ601's approach is outlined here. As an aside, my IDE (Netbeans) maps its Build menu-command to mvn install by default for this purpose.

It is likely a module definition, module use, or dependency issue.  I suspect that you don't understand and properly use modules, but you could have other issues.  An example of setting up a JavaFX project having a dependency on another project is in the answer to JavaFX complex project architecture (and the links off that answer).

I don't use the javafx-maven-plugin to run JavaFX apps (I find it doesn't provide a lot of value for that, unless perhaps you were running from the command line).  For a modular project, I will use a new JavaFX project generated by Idea and run the app in the IDE as instructed in that guide.

For a non-modular project, I will start with the same generated project, delete the module-info.java, download the matching JavaFX SDK version from Gluon, and set the VM arguments in the IDE manually to add the JavaFX modules (or instead just use a JDK that includes JavaFX like Azul JDK FX or Liberica Full JDK).   Anyway, just mentioning that so that you are aware that there are other options.

@jewelsea To provide some extra context: This is a very large existing application and im currently doing an upgrade/migration from Oracle JDK 8 to OpenJDK 17. Its a requirement to use the RedHat distro of openjdk (which doesn't include JavaFX). I want to be able to run it with this plugin (or more so with maven) since we have a lot of run configurations for this app (+/- 12) and we prefer not using the IntelliJ run configuration since there's no guarantee that the correct OpenJFX version would be used since the SDK would need to be downloaded separately and linked to from every run config

@trashgod This is a non-modular project. Besides that, I don't understand how the approach outlined in your link relates to the suggestion SedJ601 made. Unless SedJ601 is talking about declaring dependencies in a module-info.java? (which this project doesn't use)

I was unable to replicate your issue.
Example Project
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>ui</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

core/pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>core</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

ui/pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>ui</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>org.example.ui.FXApp</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

ui/src/main/java/org/example/ui/FXApp.java
package org.example.ui;

import jakarta.transaction.TransactionManager;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String transactionInfo = "Transaction Manager: " + TransactionManager.class;
        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        new Label(
                                transactionInfo
                        )
                )
        );
        stage.show();
    }
}

Build
Command:
mvn install

Output:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for parent 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.234 s]
[INFO] core ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.809 s]
[INFO] ui ................................................. SUCCESS [  0.815 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Execution
Command:
mvn -f ui javafx:run

Output:

Notes
I added a dependency in the core project to the jakarta transaction manager rather than the javax transaction manager as the javax transaction manager is obsolete.
If you are going to the effort to upgrade from Oracle JDK 8, I would recommend as a minimum using the latest LTS JDK/JavaFX releases (21) rather than 17.  Newer JavaFX releases will not support Java 17.
